# Elliptic curve Resources

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am working on  eliptic curve for text encryption using Java  and I have been wondering what is the best elliptic curve should I use?

It will helpfull if you provide me with resources
Where I find  all elliptic curves types and its parameters .

Thank you

Comment: Current state of the art is Curve25519.

Answer (score 1):

The [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) site by Bernstein and Lange has a list of common / interesting curves. Note that the site is not really targeting developers; this is about cryptographic research / science

It *may* contain some bias by the authors in the sense that they may overstate the importance of the security properties that are not fulfilled by the curves (and that are fulfilled by their own curve - Curve22519 - of course).

As it is a scientific resource, you can get all the references to the original specs from there.

---

Anybody that is introduced to EC mathematics may create their own set of parameters for a specific EC curve equation. So you will never find all curve parameters. Some curves are probably only used within organizations / states.

Other curve parameters are just generated by e.g. governments to make sure that the generation of these parameters is controlled to *their* satisfaction. E.g. the French have their own 256 bit prime curve that is not really special in any kind of way compared to P-256 / secp256r1.

Curve22519 is special in the sense that it doesn't require any "random" parameters initially, so there is no way that the organization that generated the curve picked "special" parameters to their own end.

---

You cannot / should not directly use EC to encrypt text. Look into ECIES if you plan to do that.